# How to get src value in Flutter?

Tags: laravel, flutter, embed, rest, flutter-video-player

I am pulling data from REST API using Laravel Passport, the data has an embed code, I need to play the video, for which I have to use ext_video_player, how can I get the src value from embed code like this:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/fUv9gO8t8b4" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I need to get the value of src.

Comment: please add your api response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if it is string or not but if it is string you can get src like this:

```
  const str = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/fUv9gO8t8b4" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
  const start = 'src="';
  const end = '" frameborder';

  final startIndex = str.indexOf(start);
  final endIndex = str.indexOf(end, startIndex + start.length);

  print(str.substring(startIndex + start.length, endIndex)); // https://www.youtube.com/embed/fUv9gO8t8b4
```

Comment: Trying to understand how did you find substring `over`?

Comment: excuse me. pick it up from some example. answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

Using this package [universal_html](https://pub.dev/packages/universal_html)

```
import 'package:universal_html/html.dart' as html;
import 'package:universal_html/parsing.dart' as parser;

final htmlDocument = parser.parseHtmlDocument(
            '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8zM-CrtJmG" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>');

log('${(htmlDocument.getElementsByTagName('iframe').first as html.IFrameElement).src}');
```